# Connection via ODBC to SQL Server failing

Tags: sql, odbc, database-connection

I have a strange issue. I can connect from one Terminal server to the SQL server as an admin. I can also connect to the server via a straight SQL connection as a normal user. When I try and log on to the server using odbc I receive the following error.

07/08/2011 10:49:14,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: 10.0.0.25]
07/08/2011 10:49:14,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 58.

The SQL server is definitely in mixed mode and a user is definitely set up in the connection. It must be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the user that tries to login does not have permission to the database he/she is trying to connect.

Go to the SQL Server > Security > Select the User - Right Click > Properties > User Mapping 
And there select the database that user needs to access (check box in the map column)

I'm pretty sure that error had happened to me before that that's how I fixed it. Assuming it is true that your server is setup as mixed mode already.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. It should be logging in as a SQL user who does have access to the server. I have tried adding the domain user to the database. The server is definitely mixed mode. There must be a permission issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your using ado.net, make sure your using the ODBC data adapter, connectors and odbcCommands instead of the SQL ones. ;)